Alternative to CCleaner for Windows
I'm looking for a Windows alternative to CCleaner to clean things like temp files, caches, recent files, things like that.  CCleaner has grown in scope, and it's cumbersome to turn off a lot of the features I don't want like automatic updates, real time scanning, etc.  Also, for some reason, the internet at large now invents weird things and says that this whole category of software is categorically bad, so there are no recommendations anywhere, for example reddit, nor via a general internet search.
I'd prefer something open source and free, but 1 time paid software would also be OK.

What do you mean by "cumbersome"? Turning these off takes like 2 minutes at most. Are you talking about setup on lots of machines?

https://www.bleachbit.org/download
The application is open source, available for Windows and Linux.
It has many features for optimizing the system and removing unused files from the disk to free up space.

Welcome! Would you mind reading https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/387/140 and posting again? Thanks a lot! :-)
